# If $|X|=n$ then $S_X \cong S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

I would appreciate if you could please express your opinion on this proof. The proof appears to be "self-evident", but, as it often happens with one trying to gain more algebraic maturity, it may not be rigorous enough, especially when it comes to apparently the most simple of things.

Proof:

$S_X$ is a group of permutations on the set $X$, thus $|S_X| = |X|! = n!$. This implies that a bijection exists between $S_X$ and $S_n$. Hence, $S_X\cong S_n$.

Comment: What is your definition of $S_n$? What you should be proving is that if $X$ and $Y$ are any two sets with $|X|=|Y|$, then $S_X \cong S_Y$. You cannot sensibly define $S_n$ until you have proved that! But the main problem with your proof is that the existence of a bijection between two groups does not guarantee that they are isomorphic as groups.

Comment: If $Y$ is a set of $n$ integers, defined as $Y = \{1,...,n\}$, then $S_Y = S_n$ is a group of permutations on $Y$. Thus $S_X\cong S_Y=S_n$.

Comment: Presumably you mean the group of all permutations of $Y$. But according to your proof, $S_3$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group of order $6$, because they both have order $6$.

Comment: The idea that if two symmetric groups have the same order, they must be isomorphic. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hint: To solve this problem you have to have a rigorous definition of $S_X$ where $X$ is an arbitrary set. To try and arrive to such a definition. What is a permutation of $Y=\{1,..,n\}$?

Comment: A permutation of $Y$ is an element $\sigma\in S_n$, correct? $S_X$ is a set of all $\sigma\in S_n$ of order $n$.

Comment: Your answer is like answering the question of "What is a bird?" by saying "it is an element of the set of birds".  There should be a definition of a permuation not refering to the set permutations.

Comment: A permutation is a bijective function $\rho: X\to X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to spell out what has been said in the comments.

Showing that two groups are isomorphic involves exhibiting an isomorphism between them. As noted in the comments, you need to identify the groups involved: Let $X$ be a set. The group $S_X$ is the set of all bijections $X\to X$ with multiplication given by composition of functions.

Now, let $X$ and $Y$ be two sets of order $n$. It is not enough that $|S_X|=|S_Y|$ since an arbitrary bijection between the two need not be a homomorphism. You need to produce a bijection that is.

*Try this:* Let $\gamma:X\to Y$ be any bijection. Define a map $\Phi_\gamma:S_X\to S_Y$ by 
$$\Phi_\gamma(\sigma)=\gamma\circ\sigma\circ\gamma^{-1}$$
You need to show that $\Phi_{\gamma}(\sigma\circ\tau)=\Phi_\gamma(\sigma)\circ\Phi_\gamma(\tau)$ and that $\Phi_\gamma$ is bijective (hint: show that $\Phi_\gamma^{-1}=\Phi_{\gamma^{-1}}$).

Comment: Why does showing that $\Phi_\gamma^{-1}=\Phi_{\gamma^{-1}}$ show that the homomorphism is bijective?